# Using PSCredentials in C# code

Tags: c#, powershell, impersonation

I am writing a binary cmdlet and I would like to accept a `PSCredential` parameter in order to use elevated credentials.

```
[Parameter]
public PSCredential Credential { get; set; }
```

There seems to be a distinct lack of documentation for this - all I can find is how to execute PowerShell cmdlets from C#, which is not what I wish to do.

I downloaded the `SimpleImpersonation` nuget package to avoid doing the Windows impersonation myself.

```
using (Impersonation.LogonUser("GLOBAL", "last.first", "mypassword", LogonType.Interactive))
{
    foreach (ServerInfo server in Targets)
        ProcessRecord();
}
```

When I check `System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name` the user is correct, but when I execute a command (eg `ServerManager.OpenRemote(computerName)`) I receive an `UnauthorizedAccessException`. If I run this code from a PowerShell instance running as the desired user the cmdlet executes flawlessly.

Does anyway have any clues as to how to utilise a `PSCredential` in a C# binary cmdlet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why this has so little documentation online. As I suspected I needed to use impersonation to accomplish this. There seems to be a lot of plumbing involved with this, [see here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w070t6ka%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

After some more investigation there's a nice nuget package called [SimpleImpersonation](https://github.com/mj1856/SimpleImpersonation).

Using:

```
[Parameter]
public PSCredential Credential { get; set; }
```

I can do this:

```
using (Impersonation.LogonUser("GLOBAL", Credential.UserName, Credential.Password, LogonType.Interactive))
```

This allows me to run commands as the impersonated user. `LogonUser()` takes the username and `SecureString` password.

This works fine for `ServiceController` calls, but `ServerManager` was still throwing COM unauthorised exceptions. I managed to find [this post](http://web.archive.org/web/20160403101316/http://arcware.net/solving-the-unauthorizedaccessexception-when-calling-servermanager-openremote/) which said to not use `OpenRemote()` but to use a ctor overload. The following code works:

```
using (ServerManager serverManager = new ServerManager(@"\\server\c$\windows\system32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config"))
{
    ApplicationPoolCollection appPool = serverManager.ApplicationPools;
    Console.WriteLine(appPool.Count);
}
```